# Visual Studio Code Nuget autocomplete failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget

Autocomplete search function in Visual Studio Code Nuget is failed , error: unable to verify the first certificate.
I have tried set in settings.js :

```
{
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

but nothing helps. The error still exists.
Error Message: request to https://api-v2v3search-0.nuget.org/autocomplete?q=Xunit&prerelease=true&take=100 failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: You should ask the question you want answered vs just stating that something has failed.  we assume you want a work around to get things going?

Comment: I was trying to search for XUnit and Selenium.Webdriver(Any keywords) in the search bar of Nuget to install the framework. but no matter what I keyed in, this error message is displayed.

Comment: I would suggest going here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues

and adding a new issue with the info above and ask for assistance in resolving the issue.